LWC - Reactivity with Object and Array not working as expected
Let me preface this by saying Reactivity in LWC tends to stump me to no end. If there is something I'm obviously missing I'll take it.
I'm currently experiencing an issue where I can't get properties to mutate in an LWC the way I want. I'm looking to do one of two things in order for a rich text field to clear on a deletion with no luck. For context, I have a Parent LWC that holds multiple Child LWCs. The child LWC has the rich text field.

In my parent component, I have a @track array initialized in a wire method and cloned by doing a JSON serialize and parse. It's used to setup the child LWCs. I'm trying to delete an element from the array, but it doesn't seem to reflect.
In my child component, I have an @api object initialized via a parent component and then reset by doing a JSON serialize and parse. It has a Comments field used to populate a Rich Text field I'm trying to clear with no luck.

Here is the full context and sample code blocks to hopefully help out with an answer:

We have two LWCs. Parent and Child. Parent has multiple childs which are initialized via an array.
In Parent LWC, we have an @track array named data. This is used to setup the child LWCs.
In child, we have an @api object called item. A property named Comments__c on item is used to populate a rich text field.
We have a button on child called delete. When pressed it does the following:

Opens a Lightning Confirm Dialog to confirm deletion.
Kicks off an API call to delete the record.
Sets item.Comments__c = null
Emits an event to parent.
In parent, removes the element from the array.



We tried using setRangeText on the Rich Text with little luck. We also tried various different ways to setup a new item like by doing item = {...,Comments__c: ''} and item = structuredClone(item). With the array, we tried doing a shallow copy and filter both.
Here is my code with what is relevant
Parent HTML
<template>
    <lightning-layout multiple-rows>
        <template for:each={data} for:item="item" for:index="index">
            <lightning-layout-item size="12" key={item.Id}>
                <div class="slds-m-around_small slds-p-around_small item-section">
                    <child-component item={item} index={index} 
                    onDelete={handleDelete}>
                    </child-component>
                </div>
            </lightning-layout-item>
        </template>
    
</template>

Parent JS
export default class parentComponent extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
 @track data = [];

 connectedCallback() {
    this.data = [];
 }

 @wire(loadData) {
   let resultList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result.data));
   let defaultData = this.getDefaultRows();
   resultList.forEach(function (currentItem, index) {
          defaultData[index] = currentItem;
        });
   this.data = defaultData;
 }

  getDefaultRows() {
    const defaultDataRow = { 'ParentId': 'SampleValue'};
    const defaultData = [defaultDataRow, defaultDataRow];
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(defaultData));
  }

  handleDelete(event) {
    const index = event.detail.index;
    // Including all the options we tried
    /*let tempData = [...this.data];
    tempData.splice(index, 1);
    this.data = [...tempData]; */
    this.data = this.data.filter((item,i)=>{
      return index !== i;
    });
    this.checkAndAddEmpty();  
  }

  checkAndAddEmpty() {
    const emptyNeeded = 2 - this.data.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < emptyNeeded; i++) {
        this.data.push({ 'ParentId': 'SampleValue'});
    }
  }
}

Child HTML
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-text-align_right">
            <lightning-button icon-name="utility:delete" title="Delete" class="slds-m-left_x-small" onclick={handleDelete} label="Delete">
            </lightning-button>
        </div>
        <div class="comments">
            <div class="slds-p-around_medium lgc-bg">
                Comments
                <lightning-input-rich-text data-id="Comments__c" value={item.Comments__c} onchange={handleDataChange}></lightning-input-rich-text>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

Child JS
export default class childComponent extends LightningElement {

    @api item;
    @api index;

    connectedCallback() {
        this.item = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.item));
    }

    handleDataChange(event) {
        var fieldName = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
        var fieldValue = event.detail?.value;
        var item = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.item));
        item[fieldName] = fieldValue;
        this.item = item;
    }

    async handleDelete() {
        await LightningConfirm.open({
            message: 'Are you sure you want to delete this?',
            theme: 'error',
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result) {
                this.deleteRecord();
            }
        });
    }

    async deleteRecord() {
        if (!this.item.Id) {
            this.emitDeleteEvent();
        } else {
            this.isDeleting = true;
            deleteRecord({ recordId: this.item.Id })
                .then(() => {
                    this.emitDeleteEvent();
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.dispatchEvent(
                        new ShowToastEvent({
                            title: '',
                            message: error.body.message,
                            variant: 'error'
                        })
                    );
                })
                .finally(() => {
                });
        }
    }

    emitDeleteEvent() {
        const deleteEvent = new CustomEvent('delete', {
            detail: { index: this.index }
        });
        
        
        this.item.comments = '';
        this.template.querySelector('[data-id = "Comments__c"]').setRangeText('',0,this.item.Comments__c.length,'start');
    
      // Other things we've tried   
      //  let newItem = structuredClone(this.item);
     //   newItem.Comments__c = '';
     
      //  this.item = {...this.item,Comments__c:'' };
     //   this.item = {...this.item};    
     this.dispatchEvent(deleteEvent);    
    }
}

